# MS Word Bookmarking Trouble

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks

I have a document with a main page that bookmarks to other pages within the document. When I save the document under a new name, the bookmarks link back to the old document, when I want them to link to the new document. How do I fix this !!!

Comment: Your title is very vague and doesn't really describe your question.

Answer (score 0):

Show field codes using ALT+F9 and do a find/replace of the old document name for the new one. Press ALT+F9 to hide field codes, then CTRL+A to select all and F9 to update.